# ssh-keyscan returns no key

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Here's an example of what my console looks like. I expect to see a fingerprint somewhere in there, like I do with other hosts. Currently using Ubuntu through Windows Subsystem for Linux. I have a list of many hosts I would like to acquire keys for. Some of them work, some don't.

```
user@user:/homedir$ ssh-keyscan -H hostname
# hostname:22 SSH-2.0-9.99 sshlib
# hostname:22 SSH-2.0-9.99 sshlib
# hostname:22 SSH-2.0-9.99 sshlib
# hostname:22 SSH-2.0-9.99 sshlib
# hostname:22 SSH-2.0-9.99 sshlib
```

Using -v to get debug log, the output looks like this:

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: (no match)
debug1: no match: 9.99 sshlib
```

When a successful keyscan would look like this:

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<8192<8192) sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
hostname ssh-rsa AAAAB...etc
```

Connecting to the server using a client (FileZilla) is successful and returns an ssh-dss 1024 hostkey. I want to get that same hostkey using ssh-keyscan.

From the [ubuntu documentation](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/ssh-keyscan.1.html#:%7E:text=ssh%2Dkeyscan%20is%20a%20utility,by%20shell%20and%20perl%20scripts.), the ssh-keyscan default key type to look for is rsa, so the user has to specify dsa in order to get the ssh-dss key for this particular host.

> -t type:
>
> ```
>          Specifies the type of the key to fetch from the scanned hosts.  The possible values
>          are “rsa1” for protocol version 1 and “dsa”, “ecdsa”, “ed25519”, or “rsa” for
>          protocol version 2.  Multiple values may be specified by separating them with
>          commas.  The default is to fetch “rsa”, “ecdsa”, and “ed25519” keys.
> ```

So in a few instances where I am unable to find a key, the following works:

```
ssh-keyscan -t dsa hostname
```

And if you want to try them all you could do:

```
ssh-keyscan -T 20 -t dsa, rsa1, rsa, ecdsa, ed25518 hostname
```

Giving it a longer timeout of 20 seconds since that might take a while. That still doesn't work for a bunch of the hosts I am trying to connect to, so I still don't have an answer.

Comment: Adding -v might provide further into to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Are you executing the command *on* your WSL instance, *against* your WSL instance, or both?

Comment: If `hostname` is the WSL instance, try a quick uninstall/reinstall of the openssh-server package.  I thought recent versions set it up correctly, but I did run across a case last week of an instance that didn't have keys created properly in the distro.  That said, you shouldn't be able to *start* the service without the keys created, so I'm not all that hopeful that the uninstall/reinstall will work.  But it's worth a shot.

Comment: No. The hostname is a host I do not own that I've successfully connected to using another application.

Comment: Is there anything in `~/.ssh/config`, and if so, what are its contents?

Comment: No such file is there

Comment: It looks like the first example host is using an sshlib-bashed ssh server, which means you are likely seeing the same problem as mentioned in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/600189/432493), which is also unresolved.  I'm assuming this means [Bitvise sshlib](https://www.bitvise.com/sshlib), which appears to be deprecated.  Likely a bug in their implementation.  Are all of the hosts that the keyscan is failing on using this library?

Comment: Hi @JacobBayer, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No unfortunately not @borizzzzz